# Mezzanine cms crashed after added user profile model

Tags: django, mezzanine

I am learning mezzanine. I just followed the quick start steps set up Mezzanine 4.4.2  project myproject and changed the local_settings to use a postgresql database. Everything ran very well until I tried to set up a user profile.  I created an  app called myapp and I followed this link to setup models and settings:

[http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/user-accounts.html#profiles]

```
# In myapp/models.py

from django.db import models

class MyProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField("auth.User")
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    bio = models.TextField()


# In settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "myapp",
    "mezzanine.accounts",
    # Many more
)

ACCOUNTS_PROFILE_MODEL = "myapp.MyProfile"
```

after this was done I then ran

```
manage.py makemigrations

manage.py migrate.
```

After these 2 steps, I then ran `manage.py runserver`. Yes, the bio and date of birth fields are available in the signup and update profile forms. However, when I used admin to add new user, I  got:

> InterfaceError at /admin/auth/user/add/
>
> connection already closed
>
> Request Method:         POST Request URL:
>    127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/add/ Django Version:
>   1.10.2 Exception Type:         InterfaceError Exception Value:
>
> connection already closed
>
> Exception Location:
>   /home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py
>   in create_cursor, line 211 Python Executable:
>   /home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/bin/python Python Version:
>   2.7.12 Python Path:
>
> ['/home/nighthawk/www/testproject', 
>   '/home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/lib/python2.7', 
>   '/home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu', 
>   '/home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
>   '/home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
>   '/home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
>   '/home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
>   '/home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

The database was actually not closed. I created another project and if I didn't add user profile model, everything was good.

when I tried to sign up a new user,  I got the following errors. The date_of_birth I entered was 1980-11-01.

> IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/
>
> null value in column "date_of_birth" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9, null, , 8).
>
> Request Method:         POST Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/?next=/ Django Version:
>   1.10.2 Exception Type:         IntegrityError Exception Value:
>
> null value in column "date_of_birth" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9, null, , 8).
>
> Exception Location:
>   /home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py
>   in execute, line 64 Python Executable:
>   /home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/bin/python Python Version:
>   2.7.12 Python Path:
>
> ['/home/nighthawk/www/testproject', 
>   '/home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/lib/python2.7', 
>   '/home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu', 
>   '/home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
>   '/home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
>   '/home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
>   '/home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
>   '/home/nighthawk/.virtualenvs/mez/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Can someone please help me out?
Do you know if there are any good mezzanine tutorials?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mezzanine-users/QhGPiA75FlQ

Comment: Thank you Stephen! I followed the link you provided and changed date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True).   it's working now...Thank you! I really love the mezzanine cms you created.